# Gauss Blur 3d image in cuda, sometimes it works sometimes it does not

Tags: c++, cuda

I'm trying to recreate one algorithm in cuda and one of steps is blur 3d image (in my case 344 x 288 x 176) and I want to use 3x3x3 Gaussian mask for it.
I use cuda 8 in visual studio community 2015 on machine with intel i7-5500U, GeForce gt840m 4GB and 8GB ram, and I'm struggling with this problem for few days now.
The issue is that when my program ends blurring function it seems to lost information about memory which is passed by pointer as argument to blurring function, it wont crash on function or cudaPeekAtLastError or cudaDeviceSynchronize, but when I run program from Nsight>Start CUDA debugging it works just fine, and if i place break point before this function and run it, cudaPeekAtLastError and cudaDeviceSynchronize step by step then it sometimes work sometimes it doesnt.
mem-check says:

========= Error: process didn't terminate successfully
=========        The application may have hit an error when dereferencing  Unified Memory from the host. Please rerun the application under a host debugger to catch such errors.
========= Program hit cudaErrorLaunchFailure (error 4) due to "unspecified launch failure" on CUDA API call to cudaDeviceSynchronize.

I have similar operations in my code and all of them works fine, and i just cant see what is wrong with this. I'm not perfect cuda programmer, I kinda know c and still learning cuda and I'm aware that my English sucks too :)

so there is this function:

```
__global__ void gaussBlur(float *img,
                          float *gaussKernel, 
                          int imgSize, 
                          int kernelSize, 
                          int *imgDims, 
                          int *gaussKernelDims) {

    float newVoxelValue = 0;
    int temp_idx = 0;
    int kernel_x, kernel_y, kernel_z, temp_i, indeksWartosciDoPobrania = 0;
    int img_z, img_y, img_x;

    const unsigned int x = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    const unsigned int y = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    const unsigned int startIdx = (x * imgDims[1] + y) * imgDims[0];

    int start = startIdx;
    int stop = startIdx + imgDims[0];

    for (int idx = start; idx < stop; idx++) {
        if (idx < imgSize) {
            img_z = idx / (imgDims[0] * imgDims[1]);
            temp_idx = idx - (img_z * imgDims[0] * imgDims[1]);
            img_y = temp_idx / imgDims[0];
            img_x = temp_idx % imgDims[0];
            if (img_x > 1 && img_x < imgDims[0] - 2 &&
                img_y > 1 && img_y < imgDims[1] - 2 &&
                img_z > 1 && img_z < imgDims[2] - 2) {
                newVoxelValue = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < kernelSize; i++) {
                    kernel_z = i / (gaussKernelDims[0] * gaussKernelDims[1]);
                    temp_i = i - (kernel_z * gaussKernelDims[0] * gaussKernelDims[1]);
                    kernel_y = temp_i / gaussKernelDims[0];
                    kernel_x = temp_i % gaussKernelDims[0];

                    kernel_x--;kernel_y--;kernel_z--;
                    indeksWartosciDoPobrania = ((img_z + kernel_z) * imgDims[0] * imgDims[1]) + ((img_y + kernel_y) * imgDims[0]) + (img_x + kernel_x);
                newVoxelValue += gaussKernel[i] * 
img[indeksWartosciDoPobrania];
                }
                img[idx] = newVoxelValue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and here is its call:

```
inline __device__ __host__ unsigned int UMIN(unsigned int a, unsigned int b)
{
    return a < b ? a : b;
}

inline __device__ __host__ unsigned int PowTwoDivider(unsigned int n)
{
    if (n == 0) return 0;
    unsigned int divider = 1;
    while ((n & divider) == 0) divider <<= 1;
    return divider;
}
int main() {
    float *out_image;
    float *gaussKernel;

    int *gaussKernelDims;
    int *imgDims;

    cudaMallocManaged((void **)&gaussKernelDims, 3 * sizeof(*gaussKernelDims)); //lets say its hard coded {344, 288, 176}
    cudaMallocManaged((void **)&imgDims, 3 * sizeof(*imgDims));//lets say its hard coded {3, 3, 3}

    std::ifstream file("image.bin", std::ios::binary);
    if (!file.is_open()) {
        std::cout << "\n\nNie udalo sie otworzyc pliku obrazu";
        return -1;
    }
    char * memblock;
    file.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    int sizeOfFile = file.tellg();
    memblock = new char[sizeOfFile];
    file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
    file.read(memblock, sizeOfFile);
    file.close();

    size = sizeOfFile / sizeof(*out_image);
    cudaMallocManaged((void **)&out_image, size * sizeof(*out_image));
    memcpy(out_image, memblock, sizeOfFile);
    free(memblock);
    //gaussKernel is loaded same way and it works for sure


    unsigned int dimX = UMIN(UMIN(PowTwoDivider(imgDims[0]), PowTwoDivider(imgDims[1])), 64);
    unsigned int dimY = UMIN(UMIN(PowTwoDivider(imgDims[2]), PowTwoDivider(imgDims[1])), 512 / dimX);
    dim3 dimBlock(dimX, dimY);
    dim3 dimGridX(imgDims[1] / dimBlock.x, imgDims[2] / dimBlock.y);

    gaussBlur<<< dimGridX, dimBlock >>>(out_image, gaussKernel, size, gaussKernelSize, imgDims, gaussKernelDims);
    cudaPeekAtLastError();
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    //if i try to access out_image here program will crush
}
```

I tried to save blurring result in other variable (other pointer passed as argument same way as image) but have same issue so i doubt it will be memory race and since it's only 3x3x3 I don't think if taking value before or after another thread do so will be significant. When for test I copy that code to cpu version and it works perfectly fine:

```
__host__ void gaussBlurCPU(float *img, float *gaussKernel, int imgSize, int kernelSize, int *imgDims, int *gaussKernelDims) {

    float newVoxelValue = 0;
    int temp_idx = 0;
    int kernel_x, kernel_y, kernel_z, temp_i, indeksWartosciDoPobrania = 0;
    int img_z, img_y, img_x;
    for (int idx = 0; idx < imgSize; idx++) {
        if (idx < imgSize) {
            img_z = idx / (imgDims[0] * imgDims[1]);
            temp_idx = idx - (img_z * imgDims[0] * imgDims[1]);
            img_y = temp_idx / imgDims[0];
            img_x = temp_idx % imgDims[0];
            if (img_x > 1 && img_x < imgDims[0] - 2 &&
                img_y > 1 && img_y < imgDims[1] - 2 &&
                img_z > 1 && img_z < imgDims[2] - 2) {
                newVoxelValue = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < kernelSize; i++) {
                    kernel_z = i / (gaussKernelDims[0] * gaussKernelDims[1]);
                    temp_i = i - (kernel_z * gaussKernelDims[0] * gaussKernelDims[1]);
                    kernel_y = temp_i / gaussKernelDims[0];
                    kernel_x = temp_i % gaussKernelDims[0];

                    kernel_x--;kernel_y--;kernel_z--;
                    indeksWartosciDoPobrania = ((img_z + kernel_z) * imgDims[0] * imgDims[1]) + ((img_y + kernel_y) * imgDims[0]) + (img_x + kernel_x);
                    newVoxelValue += gaussKernel[i] * img[indeksWartosciDoPobrania];

                }
                img[idx] = newVoxelValue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Image is binary saved file from matlab (read in c++ then modified and saved works perfectly fine back in matlab) values in range 0.0f:~900.0f. GaussKernel is binary saved file from matlab (read in c++ then modified and saved works perfectly fine back in matlab) summ of all values is equal to 1.

To be precise i copy/paste gaussBlur() here but main is copied from few places in my code so i propably missed something

thanks for all advices in advance,
best regards,
Wojciech Serafin

EDIT:
As Robert Crovella said i comments WDDM TDR timeout was reason for my code act like this. Sorry for bothering You, I might make to little research in this area before I asked.

Comment: perhaps you don't understand how `sizeof()` works.  Suggestion:  print out the allocation sizes and see if it matches what you expect.  You are supposed to provide a complete code for questions like this.  That would be something that someone could compile and run and see the issue, without having to add anything or change anything.

Comment: u mean sizeof(*gaussKernelDims)? it should give me size of pointer type in bytes, so in this case it should be equals to sizeof(int)? so that works as i expected because it returns 4. Ok i'll retrieve working compilable code, its pointless to post whole because its only small part that doesnt work. And i thought that it might be something obvious that i just missed.

Comment: The unspecified launch failure means kernel execution hit a fault while it was executing. This is usually either an illegal operation, such as accessing an array out-of-bounds, or a kernel timeout. On windows, your GPU will be limited to running kernels of durations of 2 seconds or less, unless you modify or disable the WDDM TDR timeout. You may simply be hitting a kernel timeout.  You can also run your code with `cuda-memcheck` which may give additional useful info to distinguish between a timeout and some other kernel execution fault. But questions like this are expected to include a [mcve].

Comment: It might make sense since as I post now, on smaller image it works fine, I'll check how to change this timeout and let You know if its work.

Comment: So it may be that you are hitting a WDDM TDR timeout.  There are many questions and answers about that here on the `cuda` tag.